# How to get the husky and ur5 packages to work in my workspace?

Tags: husky, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded the packages for both the ur5 and the husky from github on my workspace (my_ws)

Husky: https://github.com/husky/husky

UR5 :https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot

and when typing this command to launch description.launch file.

```
roslaunch husky_description description.launch model:='$(find husky_description)/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro'D
```

I get this error message :

```
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/ros/my_ws/src/husky/husky_description/urdf/description.xacro'     laser_enabled:=false     ur5_enabled:=false     kinect_enabled:=false     ] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(env HUSKY_DESCRIPTION)'     laser_enabled:=$(arg laser_enabled)     ur5_enabled:=$(arg ur5_enabled)     kinect_enabled:=$(arg kinect_enabled)     " name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I appreciate the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226229/how-to-get-the-husky-and-ur5-packages-to-work-in-my-workspace-?/) by [Baker Salama](https://answers.ros.org/users/25752/baker-salama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-10**:
Could you please give a more descriptive title to your question? Your question is very specific about Husky and UR5, and how to use them. Your question title does not really reflect that. It will probably help to get more appropriate answers.

**Comment by [Baker Salama](https://answers.ros.org/users/25752/baker-salama/) on 2016-02-10**:
Thank for pointing that out, i have edited the title now, hope this will be more detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-*` it will find additional packages are available. Installing them should fix it (it does on the install where I can replicate your issue)

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0